# Model binding issue in ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am facing this weird issue in my `WEB API` project.
Here's the code snippet of my project:

**Model Class:**

```
       [DataContract]
       public class StudentInfo
       {
         [Key]
         [DataMember]
         [StringLength(20)]
         public string StudentId {get; set;}

         [Key]
         [DataMember]
         [StringLength(20)]
         public string FirstName {get; set;}

         [Key]
         [DataMember]
         [StringLength(20)]
         public string LastName {get; set;}

         [DataMember]
         [StringLength(20)]
         public string ContactNumber {get; set;}

         [DataMember]
         [StringLength(20)]
         public string Gender {get; set;}

         [DataMember]
         [StringLength(20)]
         public string Course {get; set;}

         [DataMember]
         public DateTime? CreatedDate {get; set;}
       }
```

**Controller Class Method:**

```
    [Route("/Student/AddNewStudent")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult AddNewStudent([FromBody]StudentInfo studentInfo)
    {
      /* Business Logic Here */
    }
```

**I am using fiddler to post the below xml to the controller:**

```
    <StudentInfo xmlns:www.w3........ xmlns:something>
        <StudentId>ST00001</StudentId>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
        <ContactNumber>9001236597</ContactNumber>
        <Gender>MALE</Gender>
        <Course>Computer Science</Course>
        <CreatedDate />    -- Value assigned from controller code
    </StudentInfo >
```

The method is invoked from **Fiddler** successfully but not all the properties are bound with the xml element values.

The studentInfo object looks something like this:

```
    StudentId        ST00001
    FirstNme         null
    LastNme          null
    ContactNumber    null
    Gender           null
    Course           null
    CreatedDate      01/01/0001T:00:00   -- Value is being changed by the controller 
                                            code later.
```

I tried removing the DatContract and DataMember attrributes but the result was same. I am using the default **DataContractSerialization** and also tried with the **XMLSerialization** but of no use.

Please let me know what am I missing here and how can I fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is missing `Order` property. I'd updated your model as follows and it was parsed as expected:

```
[DataContract]
public class StudentInfo
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string StudentId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Course { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 6)]
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Also consider skipping `CreatedDate` in the request since you expect server to fill it in. The body should look like the following (don't forget to replace `MvcApplication3.Controllers` to your namespace:

```
  <StudentInfo xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MvcApplication3.Controllers">
        <StudentId>ST00001</StudentId>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
        <ContactNumber>9001236597</ContactNumber>
        <Gender>MALE</Gender>
        <Course>Computer Science</Course>
    </StudentInfo >
```

Comment: The code worked fine after adding the Order property. Thanks a lot... :)